# Determine whether app launches AOT binary (or force it)

Tags: android

I am developing an Android Test App and was wondering if it is possible to tell whether the app is running in Interpreter Mode, JIT-Mode or AOT-compiled mode.

I am not sure if this is something that can be figured out at runtime, or if it appears in logcat logs, or what.

The [Android docs](https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime/jit-compiler) indicate that the app can be running in either AOT-compiled mode, or interpreter or interpreter + JIT.

I've run the commands to manually compile the apks:

```
$ adb shell cmd package compile -m speed -f my-package
```

But there is no confirmation that the app that I am launching is using that compiled version vs the DEX version, or even that the code that I am executing after loading the app is the compiled code versus the DEX code.

I have seen that the APK folder contains ODEX files. The docs say that if an `.oat` file is available, that will be launched (here I have `.odex` files, which I think are the same), but they also say that they might not contain all the methods or code at all. And the question is... Does that get logged anywhere?

Is there a way to either verify that my code is running with the AOT-compiled version, or to force it to run that way?

This is purely for debugging purposes.